# Mono.Cecil - How to get custom attributes

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, mono, mono.cecil

I am trying to use Cecil to inspect the attributes associated with a given method. It seems to find it, but I cannot get its name using the following code:

```
AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly(pathBin);
assembly.MainModule.Types[0].Methods[1].CustomAttributes[0].ToString()
```

I know this must be the attribute I've set my function to, because when I remove it from the dll, the second line of code will turn out to null. What I'd like to do is be able to get the attribute's name. Currently the second line of code will return just a "Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute". I'd guess there should be a way of getting an attribute's name(class type) name, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had trouble with this when writing [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) as well.  Here is the code it uses:

```
AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly(pathBin);
assembly.MainModule.Types[0].Methods[1].CustomAttributes[0].Constructor.DeclaringType.ToString()
```

Comment: Funny. That was what I was using now too.

Comment: I got that from the author of Cecil, so I think that's the only way.

Comment: I am not able to find "AssemblyFactory" class anywhere. I have found all other classes but not this. It seems that this class is not present in mono.cecil dll. Is it present in some other namespace? Can anyone please help me.

Comment: The new version of Cecil (0.9.4) has a different API.  The equivalent to load an assembly is AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly ().

Answer (score -3):

A `CustomAttribute` is an instance of a `System.Attribute` derived Type, so `ToString()` will do whatever the author decided.

If you want to know about attribute types you should ask for their type:

```
typeInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false)[0].GetType().ToString() ;
```

I haven't seen this property `CustomAttributes` you are using, so I rather used the method `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(bool)` which I always use.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not using reflection, I am using cecil. That looks like reflection, right?